# Missing Insert Data - PostgreSQL & Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, pgadmin

I try to insert some data to my PostgreSQl-DB with Python (psycopg2).

Every works fine with my `SELECT`-statement like:

```
cur = g.db.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT id FROM mydb where weight>%(weight)s and length<=%(length)s;""",{'weight':weight,'length':length})
```

Now I try to add some new data, the same way as above. The code is like

```
cur = g.db.cursor()
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO mydb (id, weight, length) VALUES (%(id)s, %(weight)s, %(length)s, );""",{'id':id,'weight':weight,'length':length})
```

But I don't see any new rows in pgadmin. Without any error message.
I copy also the statement into pgadmin's SQL-Editor and everything works fine.

Has someone some tips to debug, trace down my error?

Comment: You should first check that a similar question has not yet been asked, either by searching on StackOverflow or on Google. A simple search immediately gave me two StackOverflow answers.

Comment: @EOL :Can you add link?

Comment: I search for approx 1.5h, but with too specific keywords. Works after I switched of my customized google search

Comment: I guess I got your mistake, you haven't put place holders for your values in VALUES()

Comment: @EOL: Thx works perfect!, but why does select work and insert not?

Comment: @CanadaRunner: INSERT does not work because you must commit the changes before they are really made in the database (by definition of a transaction). Now, I guess that SELECT works because it does not cause the database to change, so there is no problem reading it (even inside a transaction).

Comment: @KishorPawar The link is displayed in the "duplicate question" box on top.

Comment: yes right, But CanadaRunner's problem is different. He needs to use commit as described in that question, but he is missing place holders too.

Comment: @KishorPawar I do agree that placeholders should be used, but that would not solve CanadaRunner's question, which is that he "doesn't see any new rows in pgadmin". PS: If you want people to see your comments, you should refer to them ("@EOL"), otherwise they won't be notified (only the author of the answer or question is notified, by default).

Comment: @EOL: oh, thatks for your tip.